# LINQ - No Results in Unit Test

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

I am creating a unit test and I have an in memory database setup using SQLLite. I have setup the db context, and when testing and stepping through I can see the data in the database context and the data that I have added in memory in the desired table.

However, when running my unit tests I get no results.

The method with the LINQ is as follows

```
public async Task<List<MissingChatActivity>> GetMissingChatActivityAsQueryable()
{
    var result = await (from chatActivity in _databaseContext.ChatActivities
            let count = _databaseContext.ChatActivities.Count(activity =>
                activity.ChatType == "live" && activity.activityID == chatActivity.activityID)
            where chatActivity.messageType == "livechat" && chatActivity.messageDirection == "out" && count == 0
            select new MissingChatActivity
            {
                Created = chatActivity.created ?? DateTime.Now,
                ActivityId = chatActivity.activityID,
                ChatType = chatActivity.ChatType,
                Count = count
            }).ToListAsync();
    
    return result;
}
```

When working against the dev and production database this gets the results that I am after so am a little confused we to whats going on.

Additionally the LINQ is shaped like this because the SQL I was given is using an OUTER APPLY as per the example below.

```
SELECT ca.created,
       ca.activityID,
       ca.ChatType,
       l.total 'Total'
FROM chat_Activity ca WITH (NOLOCK)
    OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT COUNT(1) 'total'
    FROM chat_Activity WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE activityID = ca.activityID
          AND ChatType = 'live'
) l
WHERE ca.messageType = 'livechat'
      AND ca.messageDirection = 'out'
      AND l.total = 0
ORDER BY ca.id DESC;
```

Production results
[image]

Test Results
[image]

The data in the test is shaped in the same manner as the records in the database to give it the best change of the test being successful.

```
databaseContext.ChatActivities.Add(new ChatActivity(
   123,
   "livechat",
   "OUT",
   $"The message",
   DateTime.Now,
   0,
   DateTime.Now,
   0,
   null,
   string.Empty,
   string.Empty,
   "bot"));
```

Any and all help as to why I am seeing a difference would be gratefully received.

Comment: Are you calling SaveChanges after adding the ChatActivity?

Comment: @scottdavidwalker, yes and was the first thing I checked when getting nothing

Comment: I'm also noticing that your query uses a lower case "out" but in your test data it is all capitalised?

Comment: the data in the production db is upper case and working with a lower case string in the where clause too so I wouldnt have thought this would be it but will give it a try

Comment: @scottdavidwalker interestingly making it upper case has worked. sometimes its the wood and the tree's... and would have taken me ages to go lets just try that

Comment: Sometimes a second pair of eyes is all you need :-)
I can't say why it's working on your production database but just bear in mind that an in-memory database just imitates a database. If the relations, integrity of the database is important in your tests then I'd recommend using a dockerised db :-)